# Ansible variables

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm a real Ansible beginner.

Is there any way to reconstruct a variable from another ansible variable?

For example, this playbook :

```
- hosts: servers 
  vars:
    ex_server1: First
    ex_server2: Second
    ex_server3: Third
    toto: ex_
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ toto+ansible_hostname }}"
```

It print :

```
ok: [server2] => {
    "msg": "ex_server2"
}
ok: [server3] => {
    "msg": "ex_server3"
}
ok: [server1] => {
    "msg": "ex_server1"
}
```

Instead of "First", "Second" and "Third".

Is there a way to print variable content instead of variable name in this situation or in a jinja template ?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookup *vars* plugin

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars', toto + ansible_hostname) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
ok: [server1] => 
  msg: First
ok: [server2] => 
  msg: Second
ok: [server3] => 
  msg: Third
```

The details about the plugin are available from the command-line

```sh
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup vars
```

Comment: Thanks that exactely what i was looking for !